# Fast way to calculate Hessian matrix of model parameters in PyTorch

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, hessian

I want to calculate the Hessian matrix of a loss w.r.t. model parameters in PyTorch, but using [`torch.autograd.functional.hessian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.hessian.html) is not an option for me since it recomputes the model output and loss which I already have from previous calls. My current implementation is as follows:

```py
import torch
import time

# Create model
model = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(1, 100), torch.nn.Tanh(), torch.nn.Linear(100, 1))
num_param = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())

# Evaluate some loss on a random dataset
x = torch.rand((1000,1))
y = torch.rand((1000,1))
y_hat = model(x)
loss = ((y_hat - y)**2).mean()

''' Calculate Hessian '''
start = time.time()

# Allocate Hessian size
H = torch.zeros((num_param, num_param))

# Calculate Jacobian w.r.t. model parameters
J = torch.autograd.grad(loss, list(model.parameters()), create_graph=True)
J = torch.cat([e.flatten() for e in J]) # flatten

# Fill in Hessian
for i in range(num_param):
    result = torch.autograd.grad(J[i], list(model.parameters()), retain_graph=True)
    H[i] = torch.cat([r.flatten() for r in result]) # flatten

print(time.time() - start)
```

Is there any way to do this faster? Perhaps without using the for loop, since it is calling `autograd.grad` for every single model variable.

Comment: [`torch.autograd.functional.hessian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.hessian.html#torch.autograd.functional.hessian) has a `vectorize` argument that seems like what you're looking for, but it's still experimental.

Comment: @kmkurn the trouble with the `torch.autograd.functional` methods is that they require a function that outputs a loss. For me this is a no-go, because computing the loss is expensive and I already have it. Recomputing it just for the Hessian would be inefficient.

Comment: Is approximating the hessian an option? Something like what [lm-bfgs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS) does. Or do you need the hessian as a final result?

Comment: @MichaelRuth the Hessian should be the final result yes. But approximating the Hessian could be an option, as long as a tolerance can be specified.

Comment: The BFGS hessian approximation strategy probably won't work here then. The strategy starts by either computing the actual hessian or an approximate (even the identity matrix can be used as an approximation here). Then the hessian is updated by summation with two symmetric, rank-one matrices.  This approximation is then used to solve a different problem. Finally, if some tolerance isn't satisfied, the hessian is recomputed and we go back to approximating it for future iterations. Since you're just calculating your hessian once and it's the final result, this strategy won't improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make it faster is using `functorch.hessian` (based on [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/49171)), however it has to recompute the loss everytime a Hessian is calculated (while I already have access to the loss). Nevertheless, i'll post it for those that are interested. I still think it is far too slow.

```py
import torch
from functorch import hessian
from torch.nn.utils import _stateless
import time

# Create model
model = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(1, 100), torch.nn.Tanh(), torch.nn.Linear(100, 1))
num_param = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
names = list(n for n, _ in model.named_parameters())

# Create random dataset
x = torch.rand((1000,1))
y = torch.rand((1000,1))

# Define loss function
def loss(params):
    y_hat = _stateless.functional_call(model, {n: p for n, p in zip(names, params)}, x)
    return ((y_hat - y)**2).mean()

# Calculate Hessian
hessian_func = hessian(loss)

start = time.time()

H = hessian_func(tuple(model.parameters()))
H = torch.cat([torch.cat([e.flatten() for e in Hpart]) for Hpart in H]) # flatten
H = H.reshape(num_param, num_param)

print(time.time() - start)
```